# Azure Pipelines - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I run unit tests which require Azure Storage Emulator in the Azure Pipelines?
I have been going back and forward with this for days now and I have no idea what I'm missing, my agent uses the Windows-2022 image and according to the documentation it doesn't have the Azure Storage Emulator anymore, so I'm downloading and running Azurite in the process as a background job (so the pipeline wouldn't hang).

However, when I get to my unit tests, the connection is refused by Azure, I can't find anything about why this could be happening.

Did anyone face this issue before and was able to solve it?

Just as a side note, the unit tests run fine locally and so does the emulator, below are a few screenshots from my pipeline.

The pipeline
[image]

Install and run Azurite script

[image]

Comment: Hi there João Silva; can I ask you to clarify something? When you say "Azure Emulator", do you mean the Azure *Storage* Emulator?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Yes, that's right

Comment: Did you ever get it working?

Comment: @tank104 not really, we had to set a live storage with queues and tables for the unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the bash task (instead of Powershell) for installing and running the azurite. That works for me...

[image]

Inline script

```
echo "Installing azurite"
npm install -g azurite
mkdir azurite
echo "azurite installed"
azurite --silent --location azurite --debug azurite\debug.txt --queuePort 10001 &
echo "azurite started"
sleep 5
```

The raw log

[image]

Comment: I'm able to install and run Azurite, the issue is that the connection is refused when I run the unit tests.
Apparently, the connection is refused because the agent is hosted in a shared environment.

Comment: Right. I saw that and was able to reproduce it. However, when I used bash instead of Powershell, the next step (curl command for the queue endpoint) worked fine. Try it by just commenting the script in Powershell step and add another bash step to do the unstall. Don't modify anything else and run the pipeline.

Comment: The commands in the script are different also. Possibly `sudo azurite` is crucial?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I'm using the windows environment, not the linux, so there is no sudo command.

Comment: @JoãoSilva bash is available in all hosted agents. You are right though that the windows agents do not have sudo available. I copy-pasted the linux pipeline code/scrrenshot while I wanted it from the windows agent based pipeline - corrected. My observation - when azurite is started by powershell step, it gets terminated as soon as the step completes. So the next step call to storage emulator fails. The same task done via bash step has different results - the azurite continues to run and the next step can interact with it. I have validated it with a simple curl command as a next step,

Comment: I switched my build agent to linux, and did this and it worked!  Linux builds are much quicker too.

Answer (score -1):

It might be due to the Storage Emulator, so check the status by going to:

```
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator
```

Run the following command-line syntax:

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe status
```

*Prints the status of the Storage Emulator.* If it's not running do the following in order:

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init
AzureStorageEmulator.exe stop
AzureStorageEmulator.exe clear all
AzureStorageEmulator.exe start
```

**OR** run the following `Batch Script` which will clean it, and start it up:

```
SET emulator="%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe"
%emulator% stop
%emulator% clear all
%emulator% start
```

**Updated Answer**, since the above applies only to the `Legacy Azure Storage Emulator` see the following suggestion. In your case is most likely the port and since you mention is a shared environment, it might be in use by another process. Seems like it truncates on the `Queue Service (10001)`. *You should eliminate a port misconfiguration*. Define another `--queuePort` or, let the system auto select an available port by running the following in console:

```
azurite --queuePort 0
```

Comment: That doesn't work, like I stated in my question, "my agent uses the Windows-2022 image and according to the documentation it doesn't have the Azure Emulator", since Azure Storage Emulator is deprecated it was been removed from Windows-2022 image, and no, I can't use the Windows-2019 since it isn't compatible with some of projects in my solution.

Comment: You mention a reference to using Azure Storage Emulator. Anyway, run the following in PowerShell `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 10001).OwningProcess`. This verifies that no other service / process is running in that port. And, post the results.

Comment: I'm able to run Azurite and verify that it's running, the issue is that azurite is refusing the connections, for what I read online because security reasons.

Comment: Interesting because it's failing at `127.0.0.1:10001`

Comment: I know, that's in the unit tests run, the install and run of azurite shows that the service was running.
Also, I tried different ports since you can sent that as a parameter and it gave the same error